# TaskCanceledException while invoking AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin.android, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am hitting an unhandled TaskCanceledException every time my code invokes an AWS Lambda. The code runs on an Android device. (It's written in C# with Xamarin.Android and references AWSSDK.Core, AWSSDK.Lambda).

1. Why is the task timing out? [**Update:** this has been figured out]
2. Why isn't the exception handled?
3. Why can't I see any diagnostics from AWS SDK for .NET in the logs?

Code:

```
public class SomeActivity: Activity
{
    private AmazaonLambdaClient mAWSLambdaClient;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(...);
        FindViewById(...).Click += ButtonClickAsync;

        // System.Diagnostics.Trace redirects to Log.Debug with TAG="System.Diagnostics.Trace"
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(new MyAndroidTraceListener("System.Diagnostics.Trace"));
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Android trace listener installed");

        // AWS logs to System.Diagnostics
        AWSConfigs.LoggingConfig.LogTo = LoggingOptions.SystemDiagnostics;
        AWSConfigs.LoggingConfig.LogResponses = ResponseLoggingOption.Always;
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        var idToken = ...
        var awsCredentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials("IdentityPoolID", AWSConfig.RegionEndpoint);
        awsCredentials.AddLogin("accounts.google.com", idToken);

        mAWSLambdaClient = new AmazonLambdaClient(awsCredentials, AWSConfig.RegionEndpoint);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();

        mAWSLambdaClient.Dispose();
        mAWSLambdaClient = null;
    }

    private async void ButtonClickAsync(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
         await DoSomethingAsync();
    }

    private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        var lambdaRequest = ...
        try
        {
            var lambdaInvokeTask = mAWSLambdaClient.InvokeAsync(lambdaRequest);
            invokeResponse = await lambdaInvokeTask; <= VS breaks here after ~30 to 60 seconds
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException e) // also tried catching Exception, no luck
        {
            Log.Error(TAG, "Lambda Task Canceled: {0}, {1}", e.Message, e.InnerException);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio breaks on the await line, telling me I have an unhandled `TaskCanceledException: a task was canceled`. Weird I do handle that exception.
After the unhandled exception, I check the Device Log in Visual Studio. I filter by TAG="System.Diagnostics.Trace" and all I find is:

```
base apk Information 0:
Android trace listener installed
```

Where is the AWS SDK log I should have gotten according to [logging-with-the-aws-sdk-for-net](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/logging-with-the-aws-sdk-for-net/)?

**UPDATE:**

I've figured out question 1, why it times out. It was due to a `lambdaRequest` with a bad `PayloadStream` set to a `MemoryStream` whose position had not been reset to 0 after JSON serializing an object to the stream.

I have not figured out why 2, the exception wasn't handled by the try/catch, and 3, why AWS SDK did not log as requested.

Comment: How and where is `DoSomethingAsync()` being called/invoked? You may have a blocking call somewhere that is causing a dead lock, resulting in time expiring and cancellation of the task

Comment: I've updated the question to show more specifically how DoSomethingAsync() gets called. It's called by a button click handler.

Comment: Ok why are you beginning the task outside of the try catch. try just `await mAWSLambdaClient.InvokeAsync(lambdaRequest);` within the try/catch and see if the exception is caught.

Comment: That would make no difference (also tested right now, same thing repros), exceptions thrown inside functions that returns async Task capture their exception and store it inside the task. The exception bubbles up when you await or Wait() the task.

The reason I keep the task creation outside the try block, is that I sometimes try to do more work that can be done immediately between creating the task, and awaiting the task. I prefer to keep my try block as close to where the exception bubbles so that I catch only what I think I will catch.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Nkosi, I figured out #1, a bug in my code that creates the lambdaRequest, code that wasn't even shared in the question. My bad but I did not think that code was relevant. Updated the question. Question #2 and #3 still puzzling me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing either the `TaskCanceledException` instance is not from the same namespace your code is expecting in the catch statement, or it is being thrown from the line just above your try-catch, i.e `mAWSLambdaClient.InvokeAsync(lambdaRequest)`. What happens if you move that line and possibly more lines inside the try-catch block?

If this doesn't help, please post the stack trace.

Comment: Good point about the TaskCanceledException possibly being thrown in a different namespace, I need to check if this is what's happening thanks. I know the InvokeAsync statement isn't throwing because I've double checked for that my moving it inside the try block and it didn't change.

Comment: Unhandled exception is of type System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException, same as what I'm catching. I updated the code to not only move the try to include everything including the invokeAsync, but also catching general System.Exception. Still not catching it...